# Show total of datagridview selected rows in toolstrip label c#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

In my win form application i need to show the sum of  my datagridview selected rows in toolstrip label, i am currently able to calculate the sum and display in the label for all the rows in my data grid view.
But my requirement is :

1. If the datagridview gets filtered the label should show only the total of that filtered rows.
2. If the user selects some rows in the whole datagridview the should show only the total of that selected rows.

please help me how to do this
here is my code so far:

```
int A = 0, B = 0;
                for (A = 0; A < iP_SpoolsDataGridView.Rows.Count; ++A)
                {
                    B += Convert.ToInt32(iP_SpoolsDataGridView.Rows[A].Cells[20].Value);
                }
                Total.Text = B.ToString();
```

image of my winform:
[image: winform image]

Comment: Do you run this code after filter is applied? Where is it located (in which event)? See [mcve].

Comment: [DataGridView.SelectedRows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectedrows?view=net-5.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int A = 0, B = 0;
                for (A = 0; A < iP_SpoolsDataGridView.Rows.Count; ++A)
                {
                    if ( iP_SpoolsDataGridView.Rows[A].Displayed && iP_SpoolsDataGridView.Rows[A].Selected)
                       B += Convert.ToInt32(iP_SpoolsDataGridView.Rows[A].Cells[20].Value);
                }
                Total.Text = B.ToString();
```

I added two conditions there in order for the value to be added to `B` (Total calc):

1. `displayed`, to ensure the row was not filtered out, and is shown on screen.
2. `selected` because you want to calculate only selected rows.

Have fun hacking!

Comment: Thank you so much it worked as per my need!